# Generic Methods or Inheritance for similar objects

Tags: c#, generics

I have my library objects, such as ObjA, ObjB, ObjC, ObjD..

I also have objects created from a web service reference, SvcA, SvcB, SvcC, SvcD..

Note that, ObjA and SvcA is similar as in, they have similar fields(but not exactly the same name)

I have the following piece of code for ObjA and SvcA mappings.

```
public static SvcA[] GetSvcList (IList<libA> libList)
{
    IList<SvcA> svcList = new List<SvcA>();
    foreach(libA libObj in libList)
    {
        svcList.Add(libA.getSvcObject());
    } 
    return svcList.ToArray();
}

public static IList<ObjA> GetLibList(SvcA[] svcList)
{
    IList<ObjA> objList = new List<ObjA>();
    foreach (SvcA svcObject in svcList)
    {
        objList.Add(new ObjA(svcObject))
    }
}

ObjA(SvcA svcObject)
{
    this.Field1 = svcObject.Field1;
    this.Field2 = svcObject.F2;
}

public static GetSvcObject()
{
    SvcA a = new SvcA();
    a.Field1 = this.Field1;
    a.F2 = this.Field2;
}
```

I cannot modify the Svc_ classes. But I can modify Obj_ classes. If I could do both, I was thinking I could do derive both these classes from a particular object and use the interfaces.

I was wondering if it is possible to avoid repeating all this code for SvcB-ObjB, SvcC-ObjC, SvcD-ObjD.. mappings.

Answer (score 0):

Automapper is probably the best tool for this job:

http://automapper.org/

Answer (score 0):

Here you can convert those `GetSvcList` and `GetLibList` to generic. Here's how you can achieve without replicating them for each type of Obj and Svc.

```
public static IList<Tobj> GetLibList<Tobj, Tsvc>(Tsvc[] svcList) where Tobj : new()
{
    IList<Tobj> objList = new List<Tobj>();
    foreach (Tsvc svcObject in svcList)
    {
        objList.Add((Tobj)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Tobj), svcObject));
    }

    return objList;
}

public static Tsvc[] GetSvcList<Tsvc, Tlib>(IList<Tlib> libList)
{
    IList<Tsvc> svcList = new List<Tsvc>();
    foreach (Tlib libObj in libList)
    {
        // Check for null as GetMethod could throw null if method not found.
        svcList.Add((Tsvc)(typeof(Tlib).GetMethod("getSvcObject").Invoke(libObj, null)));
    }

    return svcList.ToArray<Tsvc>();
}
```

Since you haven't provided much details about your Obj classes so can't suggest you anything about that. But if you have same properties then [Automapper](http://automapper.org/) could be a great choice for mapping object properties having same names.

Comment: Thanks. The objects have different fields, so a direct mapping is not possible. I am not sure if automapper would be very useful in that case.
 I can instead define getSvcObject and the constructor for each Lib class so that I can create lists using code above. T

Comment: Yup!! that's the way to go.